# Tridion UI Update Preview Bad Request

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, configuration, experience-manager

I receive a "Bad Request" response when clicking "Update Preview" within Tridion UI.  I see other people have experienced this issue but the error I receive only occurs when a binary over a certain size is included within the page (~2mb).

Not sure why though - cd_deployer_conf.xml for UI deployer service has the following set:

`<HTTPSReceiver MaxSize="104857600" Location="C:\tridion\incomingui" InProcessDeploy="true" />`

and web.config has

`<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />`

Is there another setting for maximum upload size for the OData service?  I have tried enabling debug logging and analysing cd_core but there is nothing obvious listed.

The normal publisher for the staging website uses the same web.config and Java settings as the UI OData service and this publish succeeds.  It is just the fast track publish that fails.

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer.  Had to update the webHttpBinding section of web.config with:

`<binding name="HttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" maxBufferSize="104857600">`

Was set to 2mb previously.